# Is there an easy way to import XML into an Oracle database?

Tags: xml, oracle11g, hl7-cda, hl7-v3

It would appear that HL7 CDA, a form of HL7 V3 is XML.

Oracle seems to have a lot of tools for the import of XML.

I have the need to accept Meaningful Use Stage 2 data which is in HL7 CDA format and put it into an Oracle database.

What is the simplest way to;

1. Create an Oracle Schema based on the specific XML structure that I will be accepting?
2. Import the XML files that I receive into that schema?

My favorite tools are PL/SQL, and VB.NET.

Comment: Be more specific. What did you do? What does not work?

Comment: I have done nothing yet. What I am looking for is help in deciding what approach to take. I have not used any of the Oracle XML utilities/API, and am wondering which if any, will allow me to do what I am looking to do in the easiest fashion.

Comment: Yes, you can do all that. Go read - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm